# what is causing apache to add connection close header

Tags: php, apache, safari, websocket, http-headers

I'm implementing websockets and I have it working everywhere EXCEPT safari which requires that the HTTP Connection header be equal to `Upgrade`.   I'm using PHP to do `header("Connection: Upgrade", true);` however Apache always returns the HTTP header `Connection:Upgrade, close`.  Safari seems to be the only browser that refuses the presence of `close` in the connection header with the javascript console error `Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'`.

My Apache config file contains:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .ws. no-gzip nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0 dont-vary
```

Every thing is over SSL port 443, f.y.i. .

## HTTP HEADERS

### `HTTP/1.1` `GET` REQUEST

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Cookie:__qca=[...]; _ga=[...]; PHPSESSID=[...]; [...]
Host:[...]
Origin:[...]
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:[...]
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:[...]
```

### HTTP STATUS `101 Switching Protocols` RESPONSE

```
Connection:Upgrade, close
Content-Type:text/html
Date:[...]
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:[...]
Sec-WebSocket-Location:wss://[...]
Sec-WebSocket-Origin:http://[...]
Server:Apache
Upgrade:WebSocket
```

Comment: Do you use `Connection: Upgrade` **request** header?

Comment: yes I start the websocket connection with `Connection: Upgrade` and Apache responds with `Connection: Upgrade, close`

Answer (score 0):

I can't accept this as an answer but is the best I have so far...

Start the websocket normally over port 80 through Apache and if there is an error then redirect the websocket to an arbitrary port that runs a custom websocket server independent of Apache so that the connection header can be properly controlled.

The huge downside to this is that the websocket on safari ios will never work in educational or business networks that have restrictive firewalls.  Therefore this answer is unacceptable.